# Getting traceback and NameErrors not being defined in a function.

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python programming, just started this year. I'm currently doing a project surrounding functions within python and i'm getting stuck. Heres what I have done so far but it gets stuck around the 3rd definition.

```
def userWeight():
    weight = input("Enter your weight in pounds:")

def userHeight():
    height = input("Enter your height in inches:")

def convertWeightFloat(weight):
    return float(weight)
    weight = float(weight)

def convertHeightFloat(hf):
    return float(height)

def calculateBMI():
    BMI = (5734 * weight_float) / (height_float**2.5)
    return BMI

def displayBMI():
    print("Your BMI is:",BMI)

def convertKG():
   return weight_float * .453592

def convertM():
    return height_float * .0254

def calculateBMImetric():
    return 1.3 * weight_kg / height_meters**2.5

def displayMetricBMI():
    print("Your BMI using Metric calculations is: ", BMImetric)

def main():
    userWeight()
    userHeight()
    convertWeightFloat(weight)
    convertHeightFloat()
    calculateBMI()
    displayBMI()
    convertKG()
    convertM()
    calculateBMImetric()
    displayMetricBMI()

main()
```

And here is the error message I get whenever I try to run it...

```
Enter your weight in pounds:155
Enter your height in inches:70
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Julian/Desktop/Python Stuff/ghp17.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Julian/Desktop/Python Stuff/ghp17.py", line 36, in main
    convertWeightFloat(weight)
NameError: name 'weight' is not defined
```

Now I've probably tried several different things each of them giving me different errors.

Any help guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

At first, you call `convertWeightFloat(weight)` while `weight` has not been defined. That's because `weight` only exists within your function `userWeight` (it's called the scope of the function). If you want `weight` to be known in the main part of your program, you need to define it there.

```
weight = userWeight()
...
```

This only works if your function `userWeight` returns a value:

```
def userWeight():
    weight = input("Enter your weight in pounds:")
    return weight
```

Same problem with `height`.

Also, in the function `convertWeightFloat`, the return statement is the last thing that will be executed. After that line, the program exits the function, in such a way that the last line is never executed:

```
def convertWeightFloat(weight):
    weight = float(weight)
    return weight
```

Basically, every variable you use inside the functions should be provided to the function (most of the time as arguments). And all your functions should return the processed value. Here is a working version of your program:

```
def userWeight():
    weight = input("Enter your weight in pounds:")
    return weight

def userHeight():
    height = input("Enter your height in inches:")
    return height

def convertWeightFloat(weight):
    return float(weight)

def convertHeightFloat(height):
    return float(height)

def calculateBMI(weight_float, height_float):
    BMI = (5734 * weight_float) / (height_float**2.5)
    return BMI

def displayBMI(BMI):
    print("Your BMI is:",BMI)

def convertKG(weight_float):
   return weight_float * .453592

def convertM(height_float):
    return height_float * .0254

def calculateBMImetric(weight_kg, height_meters):
    return 1.3 * weight_kg / height_meters**2.5

def displayMetricBMI(BMImetric):
    print("Your BMI using Metric calculations is: ", BMImetric)

def main():
    weight = userWeight()
    height = userHeight()
    weight_float = convertWeightFloat(weight)
    height_float = convertHeightFloat(height)
    bmi = calculateBMI(weight_float, height_float)
    displayBMI(bmi)
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `main` function you're passing in `weight` but haven't defined it. You probably want to save the value from `userWeight`:

```
def userWeight():
    weight = input("Enter your weight in pounds:")
    return weight

def main():
    weight = userWeight()
    ...
    convertWeightFloat(weight)
```

You're also returning `weight` before you compute it:

```
def convertWeightFloat(weight):
    return float(weight)
    weight = float(weight)
```

Move the `return` statement after the calculation:

```
def convertWeightFloat(weight):
    weight = float(weight)
    return float(weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

in main() you call

convertWeightFloat(weight)

but there is no weight defined